# npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, npm

I want to install npm. I've updated everything but I can't fix the problem.

The message I get is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` to fix the dependencies!

Comment: Bugs are reported already: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/npm/+bug/1517491 and bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/npm/+bug/1809828 . put a reference there to here. please mark yourself as affected if so. thank you

Answer (score 269):

I was able to install npm by doing following:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev node-gyp libssl1.0-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: This is what fixed it, you rock

Comment: had issues on ubuntu 18.04 where nodejs installed but not npm, this fixed my problems

Comment: To anyone applying this solution: make sure you review the changes before applying them, as it might remove some installed packages to resolve dependencies. In my case, Jasp and a couple more packages were removed in the process.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04:The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev

Comment: First I had to do "sudo apt-get update", then followed this.

Comment: Worked for me on 18.04.3

Comment: Works, but it uninstalled a lot of installed packages like the whole of ros-melodic.

Comment: worked on ubuntu 18.04 . thank you .

Comment: apt-get update was enough for me.

Comment: As @SagunManSinghShrestha mentioned, it ruins ROS and Ignition installation. Read the long list of packages to be removed before you press Y.

Comment: This command works great using on ubuntu 18.04 Virtualbox Machine for Odoo 10.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 does not work

E: Package 'nodejs-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: Fantastic. The best solution to solve this problem. Much obliged.

Comment: It worked on my PC, thanks!

Comment: You can make it work with ROS without removing the packages using an isolated environment with [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv). It really avoided me a headache.

Comment: E: Package 'nodejs-dev' has no installation candidate